# System Random Hard Freeze. Are my CPU's pins bent?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, freeze

I've just upgraded RAM and CPU in my MSI-G31 P21(MS-7529) motherboard to 2X2GB DDR2(800Mhz) and CPU - Core 2 Duo 3.14Ghz 2 Core.

Before upgrading, my PC used to randomly hard freeze. I thought if I upgrade my problem will be gone. But the problem persisted even that sometimes playing games, watching movies, typing in notepad and even while booting up.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Updated BIOS
- Updated all drivers
- Did HDD and RAM test (No problem found)
- Checked CPU temp: it stays around 57-60°C
- Ambient temperature stays around : 36-37°C
- My PSU - 200W on 12V it gives 20A
- My CPU fan stays around 1700-1900 RPM. Sometimes,  it stays on 2000RPM.
- Reinstall of Windows

None of these worked.

Here's my CPU socket pins image. I doubt that the CPU pins are bent. Look at the image and tell me, please.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you reinstall Windows on a different drive?

Comment: This computer is over a decade old. Look for leaky caps on the motherboard and in the PSU. Or just stop dumping good money into it and buy a new computer. You'll probably end up spending less overall.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Nope! Okay